# How to add a shadow to the top of a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I want to add a shadow to the top and bottom of a single table view cell
I currently have this, but it only applies the shadow to the bottom of that cell.

```
    cell.layer.shadowColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset     = CGSize.zero
    cell.layer.shadowRadius     = 4
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity    = 0.3
    let shadowFrame: CGRect     = cell.layer.bounds
    let shadowPath: CGPath      = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).cgPath
    cell.layer.shadowPath       = shadowPath
    cell.layer.masksToBounds    = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem - in the table view the cells are layered  in the view hierarchy from bottom to top (this is how the OS arranges the table).

So if a shadow is applied to only one cell in the middle of the table, the cell above it in the table is layered on top of it in the view hieararcy thus covering the top portion of the shadow layer.

To fix this I added this line

```
cell.layer.zPosition        = 50
```